# Phabricator git command not found

Tags: php, git, phabricator

I have followed Phabricator installation & configuration guides:
http://www.phabricator.com/docs/phabricator/article/Installation_Guide.html
http://www.phabricator.com/docs/phabricator/article/Configuration_Guide.html

When I navigate to `http://localhost` to do final setup I get this message that says **it can not find git command** (there is also warning that "**warn  pcntl is not available!**":

```
PHABRICATOR SETUP

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                This setup mode will guide you through setting up your Phabricator configuration.


>>>  CORE CONFIGURATION  -------------------------------------------------------

 okay  PHP's deprecated 'safe_mode' is disabled.
 okay  'open_basedir' is not set.
[WARN] You have not configured 'security.alternate-file-domain'. This makes your installation vulnerable to attack. Make sure you read the documentation for this parameter and understand the consequences of leaving it unconfigured.
 okay  $PATH is nonempty.
[OKAY] Core configuration OKAY.


>>>  REQUIRED PHP EXTENSIONS  --------------------------------------------------

 okay  Extension 'mysql' installed.
 okay  Extension 'hash' installed.
 okay  Extension 'json' installed.
 okay  Extension 'openssl' installed.
 okay  Extension 'mbstring' installed.
 okay  Extension 'iconv' installed.
 okay  Extension 'curl' installed.
 okay  PHP binary found on the command line.
 okay  PHP is available from the command line.
 okay  'php' is CLI SAPI.
 warn  pcntl is not available!
[WARN] *** WARNING *** pcntl extension not available. You will not be able to run daemons.


>>>  GIT SUBMODULES  -----------------------------------------------------------

EXCEPTION!
exception 'CommandException' with message 'Command '(cd '/Users/piotr/Phabricator/phabricator' && git submodule status)' failed with error #127:
stdout:

stderr:
sh: git: command not found

' in /Users/piotr/Phabricator/libphutil/src/future/exec/ExecFuture.php:334
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/piotr/Phabricator/libphutil/src/future/exec/execx.php(34): ExecFuture->resolvex()
#1 /Users/piotr/Phabricator/phabricator/src/infrastructure/PhabricatorSetup.php(264): execx('(cd %s && git s...', '/Users/piotr/Ph...')
#2 /Users/piotr/Phabricator/phabricator/webroot/index.php(121): PhabricatorSetup::runSetup()
#3 {main}
```

**I also want to mention that I have git and I can run it without problems from terminal.**

Comment: Which part of `sh: git: command not found` is hard to understand? Having git on the system itself is only a pre-condition to have it available under sh, too. In that case it is not available under sh, as the error states. You need to make it available under sh.

Comment: What is not the case? Git is not available under sh for the PHP user? Do you know which user and shell is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it.

The problem was in missing pcntl extension in PH. I had to compile it from source (as described here: http://blog.lancerushing.com/2011/02/getting-phps-pcntl-working-on-snow.html).

Answer (score 1):

Find the user which your web server is running on, and find out if `git` is included in the `path` environment variable of that user.